# Does SQL Server 2008 have "stock" table parameter types?

Tags: sql-server-2008, table-valued-parameters

Does SQL Server 2008 offer any pre-defined table types for use with table-valued parameters?

For instance, if I just want to pass in a list of integers as a table, and derive necessary context from the other parameters I'm passing in, is there a type in place for that, or would I have to create it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no system table types as far as I know.
They are pretty easy to make though...

```
create type dbo.IntList as table (
  Value int not null
)
```

Comment: Are these kind of tables available on other DBs?

Comment: @Captain Giraffe: I couldn't tell you. I've only ever worked with SqlServer, and they were new in SqlServer2008.